# Loop being ignored by Python

Tags: python, class, loops, input

I'm a beginner to python, and when trying to see if I could make a simple program myself, I ran into this problem:

```
class y:
    def out(self):
            print("restarting")
choice = y
choice.out
while choice == y:    # loop until user stops
    while j >= 0:   # loop until j < 0
            print('lives:', j)
            j = j - 1
    print('out of lives!')
    print('restart?')
    choice = input(' Y or N ')    # Ask user to restart or not
```

Everything works once, but Python seems to ignore the first loop (while choice == y). Have I forgotten a step, or am I doing this wrong altogether?

Comment: What output are you getting, and what are you expecting?

Comment: Is this your actual code? I ran it and got `NameError: name 'j' is not defined`

Comment: Also, the mixed indentation (4 and 8 spaces) might be a problem.

Comment: what is the value of j

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need a `class y` here. If you just want to loop until `choice` isn't the character "y", then you can use ordinary strings.

```
choice = "y"
while choice == "y":    # loop until user stops
    j = 3
    while j >= 0:   # loop until j < 0
        print('lives:', j)
        j = j - 1
    print('out of lives!')
    print('restart?')
    choice = input(' Y or N ')    # Ask user to restart or not
```

Result:

```
lives: 3
lives: 2
lives: 1
lives: 0
out of lives!
restart?
 Y or N y
lives: 3
lives: 2
lives: 1
lives: 0
out of lives!
restart?
 Y or N n
```

The program loops until the user enters a value other than "y".